# Python: Replace typographical quotes, dashes, etc. with their ascii counterparts

Tags: python, string

On my website people can post news and quite a few editors use MS word and similar tools to write the text and then copy&paste into my site's editor (simple textarea, no WYSIWYG etc.).

Those texts usually contain "nice" quotes instead of the plain ascii ones (`"`). They also sometimes contain those longer dashes like `–` instead of `-`.

Now I want to replace all those characters with their ascii counterparts. However, I do not want to remove umlauts and other non-ascii character. I'd also highly prefer to use a proper solution that does not involve creating a mapping dict for all those characters.

All my strings are unicode objects.

Comment: Why not just use unicode (I know you know that's an option)? Also, there is an official unicode list of confusable characters which might assist if you have to roll your own.

Comment: I do use UTF8/unicode. Some people use the textarea to write their content so right now I have a mix of both quote/dash styles depending on who wrote something which is rather ugly.

Comment: How about a markdown formatter to normalize that stuff?

Comment: Well I'm looking for something that normalizes "that stuff". It doesn't matter if it's done before or after the markdown=>html conversion. I'd highly prefer to do it before though since then I can store the properly normalized string in my database.

Comment: Would be very happy to know what you ended up doing about this.

Comment: Define "proper solution" better.  A mapping dict is how similar functions are coded in the standard library.  It's not pretty code because it's not a pretty problem.

Answer (score 14):

What about this? 
It creates translation table first, but honestly I don't think you can do this without it.

```
transl_table = dict( [ (ord(x), ord(y)) for x,y in zip( u"‘’´“”–-",  u"'''\"\"--") ] ) 

with open( "a.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8" ) as f_out : 
    a_str = u" ´funny single quotes´ long–-and–-short dashes ‘nice single quotes’ “nice double quotes”   "
    print( " a_str = " + a_str, file = f_out )

    fixed_str = a_str.translate( transl_table )
    print( " fixed_str = " + fixed_str, file = f_out  )
```

I wasn't able to run this printing to a console (on Windows) so I had to write to txt file.
The output in the a.txt file looks as follows:

> a_str =  ´funny single quotes´ long–-and–-short dashes ‘nice single
>   quotes’ “nice double quotes”     fixed_str =  'funny single quotes'
>   long--and--short dashes 'nice single quotes' "nice double quotes"

By the way, the code above works in Python 3. If you need it for Python 2, it might need some fixes due to the difference in handling Unicode strings in both versions of the language

Comment: `'−'` (U+2212 MINUS SIGN) might be another character to add. Of course the list can be long.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such "proper" solution, because for any given Unicode character there is no "ASCII counterpart" defined.

For example, take the seemingly easy characters that you might want to map to ASCII single and double quotes and hyphens. First, lets generate all the Unicode characters with their official names. Second, lets find all the quotation marks, hyphens and dashes according to the names:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unicodedata

def unicode_character_name(char):
    try:
        return unicodedata.name(char)
    except ValueError:
        return None

# Generate all Unicode characters with their names
all_unicode_characters = []
for n in range(0, 0x10ffff):    # Unicode planes 0-16
    char = chr(n)               # Python 3
    #char = unichr(n)           # Python 2
    name = unicode_character_name(char)
    if name:
        all_unicode_characters.append((char, name))

# Find all Unicode quotation marks
print (' '.join([char for char, name in all_unicode_characters if 'QUOTATION MARK' in name]))
# " « » ‘ ’ ‚ ‛ “ ” „ ‟ ‹ › ❛ ❜ ❝ ❞ ❟ ❠ ❮ ❯ ⹂ 〝 〞 〟 ＂   

# Find all Unicode hyphens
print (' '.join([char for char, name in all_unicode_characters if 'HYPHEN' in name]))
# - ­ ֊ ᐀ ᠆ ‐ ‑ ‧ ⁃ ⸗ ⸚ ⹀ ゠ ﹣ － 

# Find all Unicode dashes
print (' '.join([char for char, name in all_unicode_characters if 'DASH' in name and 'DASHED' not in name]))
# ‒ – — ⁓ ⊝ ⑈ ┄ ┅ ┆ ┇ ┈ ┉ ┊ ┋ ╌ ╍ ╎ ╏ ⤌ ⤍ ⤎ ⤏ ⤐ ⥪ ⥫ ⥬ ⥭ ⩜ ⩝ ⫘ ⫦ ⬷ ⸺ ⸻ ⹃ 〜 〰 ︱ ︲ ﹘
```

As you can see, as easy as this example is, there are many problems. There are many quotation marks in Unicode that don't look anything like the quotation marks in US-ASCII and there are many hyphens in Unicode that don't look anything like the hyphen-minus sign in US-ASCII.

And there are many questions. For example:

- should the "SWUNG DASH" (⁓) symbol be replaced with an ASCII hyphen (-) or a tilde (~)?
- should the "CANADIAN SYLLABICS HYPHEN" (᐀) be replaced with an ASCII hyphen (-) or an equals sign (=)?
- should the "SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK" (‹) be replaces with an ASCII quotation mark ("), an apostrophe (') or a less-than sign (<)?

To establish a "correct" ASCII counterpart, somebody needs to answer these questions based on the use context. That's why all the solutions to your problem are based on a mapping dictionary in one way or another. And all these solutions will provide different results.

Answer (score 7):

You can build on top of the [unidecode](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode) package.

This is pretty slow, since we are normalizing all the unicode first to the combined form, then trying to see what unidecode turns it into. If we match a latin letter, then we actually use the original NFC character. If not, then we yield whatever degarbling unidecode has suggested. This leaves accentuated letters alone, but will convert everything else.

```
import unidecode
import unicodedata
import re

def char_filter(string):
    latin = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+')
    for char in unicodedata.normalize('NFC', string):
        decoded = unidecode.unidecode(char)
        if latin.match(decoded):
            yield char
        else:
            yield decoded

def clean_string(string):
    return "".join(char_filter(string))

print(clean_string(u"vis-à-vis “Beyoncé”’s naïve papier–mâché résumé"))
# prints vis-à-vis "Beyoncé"'s naïve papier-mâché résumé
```

Comment: This solution is ultimately a big mapping dict. And some of the mapping decisions there are unusual. For example, it will map the em dash (—) to two hyphens (--).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the str.translate() method (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).  However, read the doc related to Unicode -- the translation table has another form: unicode ordinal number --> unicode string (usually char) or None.

Well, but it requires the dict.  You have to capture the replacements anyway.  How do you want to do that without any table or arrays?  You could use str.replace() for the single characters, but this would be inefficient.

Comment: I was hoping that there's some smart way to translate only characters that are not letters.

Answer (score 0):

This tool will normalize punctuation in markdown: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html

> -S, --smart Produce typographically correct output, converting straight quotes to curly quotes, --- to em-dashes, -- to en-dashes,
>   and ... to ellipses. Nonbreaking spaces are inserted after certain
>   abbreviations, such as “Mr.” (Note: This option is significant only
>   when the input format is markdown or textile. It is selected
>   automatically when the input format is textile or the output format is
>   latex or context.)

It's haskell, so you'd have to figure out the interface.

Comment: Although not providing a Python solution this is a useful reference.