# How to deal with variations in apostrophe ’ and '

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, apostrophe, punctuation

I am doing an NLP processing and I have tweets with text as I’ll instead of I'll. Same is the case with quotation marks: “God please save us” instead of "God please save us"

My approach in pandas series:

```
tweets.str.replace(r"’", "'")
```

I expect other variations. What is the industry approach to standardizing? Many thanks.

Comment: Is the punctuation important to your NLP model?  If not, you could just remove all non-letter characters from the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Replace typographical quotes, dashes, etc. with their ascii counterparts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294032/python-replace-typographical-quotes-dashes-etc-with-their-ascii-counterparts)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer it is important for dealing with contractions. I will convert (I'll) to (I will). The contraction is a dictionary and will not support the varied apostrophe. I do other processing that removes punctuation later on among other things.

Comment: @jpl It does many thanks!